# Should the return value of "save" always be checked when using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, coding-style

In general, should the return value of `save` always be checked when using ActiveRecord?

For example, I've come across some code like this:

```
def foo(active_record_instance)
  active_record_instance.field_1 = 'a'
  active_record_instance.field_2 = 'b'
  # ...15 more lines...
  active_record_instance.save # <==
  baz = bar(active_record_instance.id)
  # ...15 more lines that use baz...
  baz
end

def bar(id)
  instance = ActiveRecordSubclass.find(id)
  instance.field_3 = instance.field_1 + instance.field_2
  instance
end
```

That's slightly contrived, but it's a fairly realistic example for the codebase I'm working on.  (This isn't an isolated case of this pattern.)

Given that the validation for `ActiveRecordSubclass` is in flux and change is possible in the near future (or even a year from now), my thought is that the return value of `active_record_instance.save` should be checked.  Another alternative would be to use `active_record_instance.save!`.

Is it appropriate to check whether or not the record saved?  Or is the `foo` method micromanaging something that should not be its concern, given that the current validation does not fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer is, `do you care about the data in question?`

If you care about the data, then yes, you should return something false or throw an exception, and somehow communicate why it failed validation.

If you really don't care if it saves, and it will be tried in 10 seconds, at which point you expect it to work, then ignore the error.

As a personal preference and experience, I would rather have something fail fast and dramatically, than spend hours or days hunting down a bug because something 50 steps before didn't actually save.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use save! method, catch exception and put your logic inside .

```
begin
  foo.save!
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  # handle logic here
end
```

Comment: To clarify: my question is more about whether an exception or return value check *should* be done.  One of my colleagues is saying to ignore whether the record saved or not.